# How to get random div with javascript

Tags: javascript

When i was on PHP interview they gave me test with PHP,JavaScript. One of the questions from JS was to get some random div ( and to do something with it, i cant remember what). I didn't get any html code and i needed to write just JS. Now i'm learning JS and i try to find solution for the question.

I try this

```
var node = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var divLength=node.length;
var randomDiv=Math.random()*divLength;
```

and now i'm testing with some code

```
<html>
<head>
<script>


  var node = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var divLength=node.length;
alert("There are "+divLength+" div tags in the html code");
var randomDiv=Math.random()*divLength;

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
</body>
</html>
```

but when i run the result is: "There are 0 div tags in the html code"

also i tried

```
var node=document.querySelectorAll("div");
```

but the result is the same.

Comment: Put your `<script>` **after** the `<div>` elements.

Comment: Or wrap it in a `window.onload = function(){/*your code here*/};`

Comment: `var all = document.querySelectorAll("*");console.log(all[parseInt(Math.random()*all.length,10)]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options I laid out below.

*You can attach an on load even to your opening body tag:*

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>

       function onLoad(){
          var node = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
          var divLength=node.length;
          alert("There are "+divLength+" div tags in the html code");
          var randomDiv=Math.random()*divLength;
       }


    </script>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad()">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
</body>
</html>
```

*Or you can move your script to the bottom of your body:*

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body onload="onLoad()">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>

        <script>       

           var node = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
           var divLength=node.length;
           alert("There are "+divLength+" div tags in the html code");
           var randomDiv=Math.random()*divLength;           

        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Either of these will force the script to run after the page loads.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your `script` is loaded before the DOM. So, when the `script` is executed, there are no `div` yet.

Placing your script after the DOM loading should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, your script is loading before the divs are created.  You can put the script at the end of the body or you can wrap it in a function and call the function after the body loads.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function manipulateDivs() {
  var node = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
  var divLength=node.length;
  alert("There are "+divLength+" div tags in the html code");
  var randomDiv=Math.random()*divLength;

}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="manipulateDivs()">
```

Or alternatively

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function manipulateDivs() {
  var node = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
  var divLength=node.length;
  alert("There are "+divLength+" div tags in the html code");
  var randomDiv=Math.random()*divLength;

}

window.onload = manipulateDivs;
</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code runs before the body is loaded, so there are no `div` elements at that time. Run it from the `load` event.

To pick an integer random number, you should use the `Math.float` method. What you get now is a floating point number.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var node = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
  var divLength=node.length;
  alert("There are " + divLength + " div tags in the html code");
  var randomDiv = Math.floor(Math.random() * divLength);
  // do something with node[randomDiv]
}
```